# VBA While loop does not iterate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project and on it I must had to check if on the same line, "I" is empty "k" must be empty too.
And if not I paint backgroud on red.

I do that code. Not crash but no effect too …

```
Sub JK()

Dim count As Integer
Dim emptyJ As Boolean
Dim emptyK As Boolean

    count = 1
    
While count = 999

    emptyJ = isEmpty(Cells(count, J).Value)
    emptyK = isEmpty(Cells(count, K).Value)

    If emptyJ = True Then
        If emptyK = False Then
            Range(Cells(J, count), Cells(K, count)).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
    Else
    End If
    
    count = count + 1
    
 Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Your While loop never executes because 1 <> 999.

Comment: For starters, you probably want `While count <= 999`. -- [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Is it important for you to solve this via VBA? Otherwise I would do something like this with plain Excel via conditional formatting

Comment: Yes i had too cause is a part of Something bigger.

Comment: I forbide Not before count = 999 my bad .. but steel Don't working. I ask seriusly my self about isEmpty …

Comment: well the function ```isEmpty``` should be fine. Although you could just say ```If isEmpty(Cells(count, j).value) then...``` If it returns ```True``` then the if statement has been met. If you need the ```count``` variable to wait until it exactly equals 999 then the ```count = count + 1``` should be outside with ```With``` statement with another ```Do``` loop encasing the ```While``` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, I would solve the problem via conditional formatting. But if you would like to do this with VBA, the following code can help

```
Sub JK()
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 10)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 11)) Then
            Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i, 11)).Interior.Color = 255
        Else
            Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i, 11)).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Ya i try dat before but unfortunately does'nt work.at all. Like Super Symmetry proposition dat color all line where "J" is empty and not "J" empty & "K" not. I will try something new. Stay here if anyone had proposition

Comment: The code snippet above marks the two cells of each row where J is empty and K is not. What exactly do you want to have? Could you show us an example?

Comment: Dat's good i just got an invisible list at J with empty and "atext" so he can't indentify this empty.. Thanks u 2 for all

Answer (score 0):

Tanks you for your propositions. They works perfectly now.
My mistakes come to the "K" cells  who are lists  with 2 propositions -" " and - "a texte".
In dat case we can't sayd "K isEmpty". But with dat code

```vb
Sub JK()

    Dim count As Long
    
    ' Change the sheet name
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")
        count = 1
        While count <= 999
            With .Cells(count, "J")
                If .Value = "" Then
                    If Not (.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "" Then
                        With .Resize(1, 2).Interior
                            .Pattern = xlSolid
                            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                            .Color = 255
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
            End With
            
            count = count + 1
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

that works

Or that one:

```vb
Sub JK()


For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
    
        If (Cells(i, 10).Value) = "" And Not (Cells(i, 11).Value) = "" Then
            Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i, 11)).Interior.Color = 255
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```